# Is there an alternative to suppressing false CA1811 with Task Panes for VSTO Word Add-Ins?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, code-analysis, office-addins

I have this method in my VSTO Ribbon

```
private void CreateTaskPane(bool pressed)
{
    ...
    pane.VisibleChanged += taskPane_VisibleChanged;
}
```

And this event handler

```
private void taskPane_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    RemoveTaskPane(pane.Window);
}
```

And this method

```
public void RemoveTaskPane(Word.Window window)
{
    ...
}
```

I've run code analysis on my solution in Visual Studio and RemoveTaskPane has been flagged with error [CA1811](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182264.aspx) - "...appears to have no upstream public or protected callers".

The Microsoft documentation says

> This rule can report false positives if entry points occur that are not currently identified by the rule logic.

Is there something I'm missing or do I just need to suppress the warning?